# Why OpenInviter sometime shows "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in.."?

Tags: php, timeout, fatal-error

Using [OpenInviter](http://openinviter.com/), i sometime (randomly) got following error and stopped working:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in...
```

How should i make OpenInviter to be stable and reliable for anytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this at the top of the php file:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

[**DOC**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: Thanks Neal.
This is the reason.
But, my webserver is not allowed that.. ;(
I wonder how can i handle that.

Comment: You could and should get a server without limitations, say, VPS.